# wcscpy_s not working for Win32 Combo Box

Tags: c++, win32gui

I'm trying to create a combo box in Win32 by following this [msdn tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298364(v=vs.85).aspx).

When I implement step 2 and try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: 'wcscpy_s' was not declared in this scope
wcscpy_s(A, sizeof(A) / sizeof(TCHAR),  (TCHAR*)Planets[k]);
```

I've included the following header files, hoping to solve this issue:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <objbase.h>
```

Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use `sizeof(A) / sizeof(TCHAR)`, you should probably use `_tcscpy_s`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error: it compiles perfectly unders MSVC2013 with a Win32 project.  Even if I undef the default VS symbols (UNICODE, WIN32, ...) I don't get the same error as you (but a complaint *error C2664: 'errno_t wcscpy_s(wchar_t *,rsize_t,const wchar_t *)'* ).  Can you tell which compiler, version, and options you've set ?

Comment: I'm using mingw. *CFLAGS := -g -Wall -std=c++11 -Wl,--stack,20971520 -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC*  ...... *SETUPFLAGS := -g -std=c++1* ..... *LDFLAGS := -s -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -Wl,--stack,20971520 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++*

Comment: Is there another function I could call to get the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

From [cpp-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcscpy)

> As with all bounds-checked functions, wcscpy_s is only guaranteed to be available if **STDC_LIB_EXT1** is defined by the implementation and if the user defines **STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1** to the integer constant 1 before including wchar.h.

Comment: I've added

    #define STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1    1   and   
    #define STDC_LIB_EXT1              2

before including wchar.h. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It says that the implementation must define STDC_LIB_EXT1, not the user (you).

Comment: Based on what you see in the tutorial, is there an alternative I can use?